# Saving file to .shp with have many attribute

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-3, kml

Is there a way to save a file to .shp with have many attribute (I use QuickOSM to create a building Layer and I tried to save but it get error).

Is there a way to change .KML to .shp?

I get error message:

> Could not make temporary scratch layer permanent. Error: Creation of
> field addr:street_1 failed (OGR error: Can't create field addr_str_4
> in Shape DBF file, reason unknown.)

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: I get this error "Could not make temporary scratch layer permanent. Error: Creation of field addr:street_1 failed (OGR error: Can't create field addr_str_4 in Shape DBF file, reason unknown.)"

Comment: Please don't repost question. Instead try to improve your older question. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for mistaken, i don't really know how to use this website so I didn't reply the last one.

Comment: then please take the [tour] and learn how we work here